# Forking and saving output of a lisp program

Tags: bash, lisp, clisp

I have a lisp program that needs to run for a long, long time. I wanted to make a bash script so that I could just do `$./script.sh&` on my school's computer and then check the output periodically without having to be personally running the process. All I want to do is call the program "clisp" and have it execute these commands:

```
(load "ll.l")
(make)
```

and save all output to a file. How do I make this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
clisp > OUTPUTFILE 2>&1 << EOF
(load "11.1")
(make)
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the nohup built-in bash command:

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

> nohup is most often used to run
>   commands in the background as daemons.
>   Output that would normally go to the
>   terminal goes to a file called
>   nohup.out if it has not already been
>   redirected. This command is very
>   helpful when there is a need to run
>   numerous batch jobs which are
>   inter-dependent

You can launch the script with nohup, and when you relog see the progress in the nohup.out file